# Rxjs observable that completes without emitting value passes unit test, but shouldn't

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, rxjs, jestjs

I have the following unit test which passes, but it shouldn't because the expected value is never emitted.

Here is a simplified example that reproduces the problem:

```js
it('should fail but value is skipped', done => {
  of(1).pipe(
    skip(1)
  ).subscribe(
     v => expect(v).toBe(1),
     () => done.fail(),
     () => done()
  );
});
```

I can modify the above code to *force* at least *one* value, but the original problem is that the *mistake* went unnoticed for a while. It seems that Jest is *happy* to pass a unit test when no calls to `expect()` are made.

```js
it('still passes', done => {
   done();
});

it('same here' () => {});
```

This becomes more difficult to spot if the observable is created *externally* to the test.

```js
it('should fail but value is never emitted', done => {
  someFunction().subscribe(
     v => expect(v).toBe(1),
     () => done.fail(),
     () => done()
  );
});
```

The above unit test passed as expected, but a bug later made the observable complete without emitting a value, and the test still passed.

Is there a way to configure Jest to fail if `expect()` is never called?

If there isn't such a feature, then what can I do differently to test asynchronous code?

Answer (score 1):

There is method [expect.assertions(number)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber) which verifies that a certain number of assertions are called during a test.

So you can modify test like this:

```
it('should fail but value is never emitted', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  someFunction().subscribe(v => expect(v).toBe(1));
});
```

Comment: Also I would recommend you to try testing with marble diagrams, developer experience with them is much better. See https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles#usage